# 14.04 on MBP 5,5 Sporadic Wireless Disconnects from Eduroam

Tags: 14.04, wireless, broadcom

As it says in the title, I have 14.04 installed on a 2009 5,5 MBP and the wireless sporadically disconnects from one specific wifi network; Eduroam. The disconnects are not after a set period of time and they appear to follow no pattern.

For the unaware, Eduroam is the wifi network used at the majority of universities in Europe, and many around the world. I have tried connecting at both my university and three other universities that I have visited recently. This has only been a problem since the beginning of this term. I have no problems connecting or maintaining a connection to any other wireless network.

I have tried this answer in another thread: https://askubuntu.com/a/60395/350115

The output of: `lspci -nn -d 14e4:`

gives: `03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4322 802.11a/b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:432b] (rev 01)`

Which did not show up in their list and thus I used the [14e4:432b] as the closest in the list and installed `bcmwl-kernel-source`

This has made no difference to the problem. I also set IPv6 to ignore, and this was also fruitless.

I don't know how to debug this connection, and it is very annoying.

The output of `dmesg` after a disconnect ends with:

```
[32902.216206] CPU: 0 PID: 382 Comm: wl_event_handle Tainted: PF       W  O 3.13.0-29-generic #53-Ubuntu
[32902.216208] Hardware name: Apple Inc. MacBookPro5,5/Mac-F2268AC8, BIOS    MBP55.88Z.00AC.B03.0906151708 06/15/09
[32902.216210]  0000000000000009 ffff880224883d88 ffffffff8171a214 0000000000000000
[32902.216214]  ffff880224883dc0 ffffffff810676bd ffff880036b88000 ffff8801d956f300
[32902.216217]  0000000000000096 ffff88020ed7c000 0000000000000001 ffff880224883dd0
[32902.216221] Call Trace:
[32902.216230]  [<ffffffff8171a214>] dump_stack+0x45/0x56
[32902.216234]  [<ffffffff810676bd>] warn_slowpath_common+0x7d/0xa0
[32902.216238]  [<ffffffff8106779a>] warn_slowpath_null+0x1a/0x20
[32902.216252]  [<ffffffffa0b97509>] cfg80211_roamed+0x89/0x90 [cfg80211]
[32902.216299]  [<ffffffffa0d9e528>] wl_bss_connect_done.isra.21+0x98/0x1a0 [wl]
[32902.216329]  [<ffffffffa0d9e82c>] wl_notify_connect_status+0x1fc/0x410 [wl]
[32902.216359]  [<ffffffffa0d9d135>] wl_event_handler+0x55/0x220 [wl]
[32902.216389]  [<ffffffffa0d9d0e0>] ? wl_get_assoc_ies+0x240/0x240 [wl]
[32902.216392]  [<ffffffff8108b322>] kthread+0xd2/0xf0
[32902.216520]  [<ffffffff8108b250>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1d0/0x1d0
[32902.216524]  [<ffffffff8172ab3c>] ret_from_fork+0x7c/0xb0
[32902.216527]  [<ffffffff8108b250>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1d0/0x1d0
[32902.216529] ---[ end trace c75447fd9358d329 ]---
[32906.860074] ERROR @wl_inform_single_bss : cfg80211_inform_bss_frame error
[32913.568439] ERROR @wl_inform_single_bss : cfg80211_inform_bss_frame error
[32917.664409] ERROR @wl_inform_single_bss : cfg80211_inform_bss_frame error
[32925.956495] ERROR @wl_inform_single_bss : cfg80211_inform_bss_frame error
[32934.244518] ERROR @wl_inform_single_bss : cfg80211_inform_bss_frame error
[32939.320069] ERROR @wl_inform_single_bss : cfg80211_inform_bss_frame error
[32943.356353] ERROR @wl_inform_single_bss : cfg80211_inform_bss_frame error
```

Comment: When you do: sudo iwlist wlan0 scan, are there several 'eduroam' networks nearby?

Comment: I get: wlan0     Interface doesn't support scanning : Device or resource busy

I then did: sudo ifconfig wlan0 up after some googling. I then found 2 eduroams

Comment: I have had this problem myself a while back, but it stopped happening. Still on 14.04 though.. I also know of some people with macs getting diconnected... *Edit: I see you're using a macbook. Maybe it really is a problem with mac wifi controllers?*